# How to add gradient on icons

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, icons

I trying to achive this type of gradient on icons but unable to do that...

Output image

[image: img]

I already use this code for that but it also dosen't show any effect

```
ShaderMask(
  shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) => RadialGradient(
     center: Alignment.center,
     radius: 0.5,
     colors: [
       Colors.pink,
       Colors.deepOrange,
     ],
     tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
  ).createShader(bounds),
  child: Icon(Icons.access_time,),),
```

What should I do for achiving that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is missing `blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn`. Play with `stops` and `colors`

```dart
ShaderMask(
  blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn,
  shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) => RadialGradient(
    center: Alignment.topCenter,
    stops: [.5, 1],
    colors: [
      Colors.pink,
      Colors.yellow,
    ],
  ).createShader(bounds),
  child: Icon(
    Icons.access_time,
    size: 133,
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: not work at all

Comment: @NicholasJela can you create new question with your best effort

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a gradient on icons using the [gradient_icon](https://pub.dev/packages/gradient_icon) package. Here's an example using the `Icons.star` icon:

```dart
GradientIcon(
  icon: Icons.star,
  gradient: LinearGradient(
    colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue],
    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
  ),
  size: 30,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
final List<Color> gradientColors = [
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.purple,
  Colors.orange
];


ShaderMask(
  blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn,
  shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) => LinearGradient(
    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
    colors: gradientColors, // Gradient colors for the icon
  ).createShader(bounds),
  child: Icon(
    Icons.message,
  ),
);
```